# SQL query failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want the query initially to return all records where c_id>0 and then filter based on the subsequent criteria supplied through text boxes. However, I am not getting any records printed the first time the page is accessed. Here is the code:

```
$ctitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ctitle']);
$csubject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['csubject']);
$creference = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['creference']);
$cobjecttype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cobjecttype']);
$cmaterial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cmaterial']);
$ctechnic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ctechnic']);
$cartist = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cartist']);
$csource = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['csource']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM collections WHERE (
    c_id>0 AND
    `ctitle` LIKE '{$ctitle}' AND
    `csubject` LIKE '{$csubject}' AND
    `creference` LIKE '{$creference}' AND
    `cobjecttype` LIKE '{$cobjecttype}' AND
    `cmaterial` LIKE '{$cmaterial}' AND
    `ctechnic` LIKE '{$ctechnic}' AND
    `csource` LIKE '{$csource}' AND
    `cartist` LIKE '{$cartist}'
    )ORDER BY c_id DESC";
```

When I echo the query I get the following printed instead:

```
request "Could not execute SQL query" SELECT * FROM collections WHERE ( c_id>0 AND `ctitle` LIKE '' AND `csubject` LIKE '' AND `creference` LIKE '' AND `cobjecttype` LIKE '' AND `cmaterial` LIKE '' AND `ctechnic` LIKE '' AND `csource` LIKE '' AND `cartist` LIKE '' )ORDER BY c_id DESC
```

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Put a space between `)` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested but still same error. I also removed some criteria and only remained with: $sql = "SELECT * FROM collections WHERE c_id>0 ORDER BY c_id DESC"; and this returned all records. But I need the criteria to work as well.

Comment: The space is also the only error I can spot... What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the braces around tow where clause elements.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I think I got it... Try replacing **LIKE ''** with **LIKE '%'**

**LIKE ''** will not work because it only shows empty columns. By **adding a wildcard** (%) it will show all rows matching everything. But it might be a better and cleaner solution to build your query completely dynamically, omitting empty WHERE conditions.

Comment: I had too many issues to resolve. Now it is working as expected. Thank you all for your help.